# Ionic / Cordova: How to force app to refresh on start, even when it was in background?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

On the homescreen of my ionic app there is a list of items, which might have changed from the last time the app was started. However, when the app was in background (multitasking) and I come back to it, it does not fire the angular $scope.init function, which loads the items and would be used on a completely new start, but instead the exact same, now incorrect items are shown.

How can I make it happen that the home-screen is always refreshed on app-start, even when it's just returning from background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cordova resume handler is your way to go (see [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.resume.html)):

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    // refresh your data here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this the Ionic way it's a differet syntax:

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {
    $state.go('some state');
});
```